# ASP.NET variable value is not persisted when used in controller through dependancy injection

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

First of all, I am absolutely NOT good at C# so if you see anything wrong with this approach please suggest how I can make it better :).

Now the problem:

I have a sort of a database manager class in which I want to maintain a userId of the currently logged in user. I have a CurrentUserId method like this:

```
public class DatabaseManager : IDisposable
 {

public DatabaseManager(IDataProtectionProvider dbp)
{

    _dataProtectionProvider = dbp;

}

private int? _currentUserId;


public int? CurrentUserId
{
    get { return _currentUserId; }
}
```

The userId is set in a separate method in the same class later down the line - I did test it, the userId is set correctly on login inside the DatabaseManager.cs

I have registered it as scoped service in my Startup.cs like this:

```
services.AddScoped<DatabaseManager>();
```

Now I have a controller (databasecontroller.cs), in which I am trying to retrieve the value I have already set in my DatabaseManager.cs, like this:

```
 public class DatabaseController : ControllerBase
 {
     private readonly DatabaseManager _databaseManager;
 public DatabaseController(DatabaseManager databaseManager)
 {
     _databaseManager = databaseManager;
 }

 [HttpPost("new")]

 public IActionResult CreateNewDatabase()
 {
     try
     {
         Console.WriteLine("cr user has value: " + _databaseManager.CurrentUserId.HasValue.ToString());
         Console.WriteLine("cr user value: " + _databaseManager.CurrentUserId.Value.ToString());
```

Hoewever, the **_databaseManager.CurrentUserId.Value** is retrieved as **null**, despite the value being set in my DatabaseManager.cs.

End Goal:
If we imagine that multiple users will be using the web api at the same time, I want my databasemanager.cs to maintain a userId for that user and their specific requests, uniquely for each user thread. The userId needs to be maintained for that specific user and be parallel to others, meaning that each user should have a separate "instance" of the databasemanager.cs. Is this even possible?

If anyone could please help that will be appreciated :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote:

> The userId is set in a separate method in the same class later down
> the line - I did test it, the userId is set correctly on login inside
> the DatabaseManager.cs

You have to make sure the `SetUserId` method is in the same scope (the same HTTP request).

You can see a null value in this scenario for example (different scopes) if the user sets the value via the '/login' route and then via the '/new' route.

Comment: Thanks @Shahar, I think I understand what you mean now. I thought that AddScoped service will make the DatabaseManager.cs be instanced for the entire controller class, but I see that for each single little HTTP request there is a separate instance. So as you say if I set the userId in '/login' that won't be visible in '/new' route. What approach can I take to achieve my end goal described in the question? What is a best practice for a login/userId maintained in runtime?

Comment: Search google about Session Management in .net. there can be various solutions: JWT tokens, cookies, or some other mechanism to persist user identity across requests (via IDP service for exmaple).

Comment: Thanks @Shahar, I see I need to change my approach. I will mark your comment as answer.